# JSONObject not workign

Tags: java, android, json

I am building an app for android.

I fire and HTTP GET request and this request returns a JSONObject. I want to retrieve the value by key. But this is not working properly.
This is the JSONObject named obj that I receive: 
`{"id":1,"name":"math","description":"This is a math course."}`

If I log `Log.d("title", String.valueOf(obj.has("name")));` this will result into true.
This works for all keys in the JSONObject.

But if I want to receive the name and do this so:

```
Log.d("title", obj.getString("name"));
```

I will get an unhandled exception: org.json.JSONException.

Does anybody know how I can fix this problem?

Comment: post your full log and stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try someting like this:

Log.d("title", obj.name);

Comment: This is how you would think it should be implemented, but no. This does not work. I think this will not work because Java is strict typed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = $.parseJSON('{"id":1,"name":"math","description":"This is a math course."}');
alert(obj['name']);
```

Try this :) You can use JSON.parse insted of $.parseJSON if you are not using jquery. Following in Java

```
String s = "{menu:{\"1\":\"sql\", \"2\":\"android\", \"3\":\"mvc\"}}";
JSONObject jObject  = new JSONObject(s);
JSONObject  menu = jObject.getJSONObject("menu");

Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
Iterator iter = menu.keys();
while(iter.hasNext()){
   String key = (String)iter.next();
   String value = menu.getString(key);
   map.put(key,value);
}
```

Comment: I am looking for a Java solution not javascript or jquery, but thanks for the effort!

Comment: I am not a Java expert but found this somewhere else :) Hope this helps (Answer edited)

Comment: The first part is about nested JSONObjects. In the while you have String key = something. and then menu.getString(key). This results in the same as object.getString("plainString"). So unfortunately this will not work for me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Everything between the { } makes part of an array, so you first need to get a JSONArray like this:

JSONArray myJSONArray = obj.getJSONArray();

And then you can access the field values with:

myJSONArray.getString("name") etc...

Search on google how to work with JSONArray.

Comment: This does not work.  Obj.getJSONArray() expects a String as parameter.

I also believe that {} is a declaration for an object. This: [{},{],{}] is a declaration for an objectArray.